# Find $f$ explicitly when $f_n$ is defined recursively and $\lim_{n\to\infty} f_n = f.$

Tags: recursion, integral-equations

Given that $f_1(x) = 0$ and
\begin{equation}
 f_{n+1}(x) = e^{-2x} + \int_0^x e^{-2t}f_n(t) \; dt, \; \text{ where }n = 1,2,\dots
\end{equation}
identify $f(x)$ explicitly where $\lim_{n\to\infty} f_n(x) = f(x).$

I have shown that $f(x)$ exists and is unique, but I am unable to find the limiting function.

Comment: First idea off my head: maybe you can show that $f(x) = e^{-2x}+\int_0^x e^{-2t} f(t) dt$?

Comment: use above equation and differentiate.

Comment: It's unique because limit are unique...

Comment: My only concern is moving the limit inside the integral without knowing how $f_n$ converges to $f.$

Comment: How about explicitly finding the first few $f_n(x)$ looking for a pattern, and then proving that f(x) must fit the pattern.

Comment: I did out the first 4 $f_n's$ twice and found an ugly pattern both times.. I think the question is more subtle than that.  It is an old qualifier question so usually any brute force computation is the wrong way to go for these.  Differentiating, then taking the limit, getting a first order ODE and attempting to solve is the best I could figure, but I was left with a non-elementary integral in the expression for $f(x).$

Answer (score 0):

### the idea

If the limit exists it will satisfy :

$$f_{\infty}(x)=e^{-2x}+\int_0^xe^{-2t}f_{\infty}(t)dt$$

if you derive this equation, you get:

$$f'_{\infty}(x)=-2e^{-2x}+e^{-2x}f_{\infty}(x)$$

### hoping that I did not make mistake, the following lines might be correct

setting $f_{\infty}(x)=e^{\frac{-1}{2}e^{-2x}}g(x)$, you have

$$f'_\infty(x)=e^{-2x}f_\infty(x)+e^{\frac{-1}{2}e^{-2x}}g'(x)$$

so $$g'(x)=-2e^{-2x+\frac{1}{2}e^{-2x}}$$

ang thus :

$$f_{\infty}(x)=e^{\frac{-1}{2}e^{-2x}}\left(e^{\frac{1}{2}}-\int_0^{x}2e^{-2u+\frac{1}{2}e^{-2u}}du\right)=3e^{\frac{1}{2}(1-e^{-2x})}-2$$

you can now verify that it satisfies the first equation.